# serving a Single Page Angular App using Restify

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, restify

I am new to AngularJs and wanted to start learning it. I was going to use Restify as my api/backend and was hoping it was possible to serve static files up for the route /.

app layout is something like this..

```
/nodesprinkler
  node_modules/
  public/
    css/
      main.css
      bootstrap.css
    js/
      angular.js
      app.js
      ...
    img/
      ...
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  server.js
  routes.js
  ...
```

My server.js looks like so:

```
var restify  = require('restify'),
    app      = module.exports = restify.createServer();

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', app.name, app.url);
});

/* Client Side Route */
app.get('/', restify.serveStatic({
  directory: 'public',
  default: 'index.html'
}));

module.exports.app = app;
routes = require('./routes');
```

How can i get Restify to serve up my static assets so it'll work like a regular express app works? I know restify is based off express, so there must be something simple that i'm missing. It will serve up / as index.html but any of my css and js files I dont have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `express.static()`

before `app.listen` put

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"))
```

The [docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
app.get("/css|js|img/", restify.plugins.serveStatic({
  directory: "./public"
}));

app.get(
  "/.*/",
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: "./public",
    file: "index.html"
  })
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm creating my futur startup with the same technologies: Restify (that I rewrite) and Angular JS for the single app view.

I've tried of lots of solutions and the best one for me is :

Keep a WS with Restify (or what you want) WITHOUT any static files... I serve it with a dedicated server (python for dev, NGinx for production).

I know this is not the expected answer but give it a try.
python -m http.server on your angular directory is so simple :p

Comment: That must be one of the most stupid answers I´ve seen, it´s like "How do I open a can of Tuna?"  Answer: "One time I was walking and doh doh eh drinking milk"..

Comment: I'm really confused that my 5 year old humble proposition make you feel so bad but, please, just use the 'answer is not usefull' button if you don't want to give arguments.